# YAML Configuration Template Issue

Tags: stellar-core, stellar.toml

So I was going from this nebula package config for AWS that was created, but I was trying to POC what the prod version of the configs for this would look like. I am not that verbose with YAML and am trying to set the QuorumSet properly but having issues. In his code from this repo here -> https://github.com/starformlabs/stellar-nebulaforge-aws

His QuorumSet looks like this

```
QuorumSet: |
        [{
          "threshold_percent": 51,
          "validators": ["GDKXE2OZMJIPOSLNA6N6F2BVCI3O777I2OOC4BV7VOYUEHYX7RTRYA7Y  sdf1",
                         "GCUCJTIYXSOXKBSNFGNFWW5MUQ54HKRPGJUTQFJ5RQXZXNOLNXYDHRAP  sdf2",
                         "GC2V2EFSXN6SQTWVYA5EPJPBWWIMSD2XQNKUOHGEKB535AQE2I6IXV2Z  sdf3"]
        }]
```

which generates a single [QUORUM_SET] with proper values below, but I need to generate a second level to this that when applied would look like this

```
# full validators (with history archive)
[QUORUM_SET]
VALIDATORS=[
"$sdf_watcher1", "$sdf_watcher2", "$sdf_watcher3"
]

[QUORUM_SET.basic]
VALIDATORS=[
"$stronghold1", "$eno", "$tempo.eu.com", "$satoshipay"
]
```

I have struggled to do so. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: upon further research it seems -> https://github.com/stellar/docker-stellar-core/blob/master/confd/templates/stellar-core.cfg.tmpl

Might be inherently flawed, disallowing a proper prod basic and advanced configuration, for current version. Looking at the template it appears to disallow this. If someone with more understanding, can describe an equivalent configuration of this that is the same, that would be appreciated or has another solution, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
NodeNames: 'GDIQKLQVOCD5UD6MUI5D5PTPVX7WTP5TAPP5OBMOLENBBD5KG434KYQ2  stronghold1,
          GAOO3LWBC4XF6VWRP5ESJ6IBHAISVJMSBTALHOQM2EZG7Q477UWA6L7U  eno,
          GCJCSMSPIWKKPR7WEPIQG63PDF7JGGEENRC33OKVBSPUDIRL6ZZ5M7OO  tempo.eu.com,
          GC5SXLNAM3C4NMGK2PXK4R34B5GNZ47FYQ24ZIBFDFOCU6D4KBN4POAE  satoshipay,
          GD7FVHL2KUTUYNOJFRUUDJPDRO2MAZJ5KP6EBCU6LKXHYGZDUFBNHXQI  umbrel,
          GCGB2S2KGYARPVIA37HYZXVRM2YZUEXA6S33ZU5BUDC6THSB62LZSTYH  sdf_watcher1,
          GCM6QMP3DLRPTAZW2UZPCPX2LF3SXWXKPMP3GKFZBDSF3QZGV2G5QSTK  sdf_watcher2,
          GABMKJM6I25XI4K7U6XWMULOUQIQ27BCTMLS6BYYSOWKTBUXVRJSXHYQ  sdf_watcher3'
      QuorumSet: |
        [
          {
            "validators": ["$sdf_watcher1", "$sdf_watcher2", "$sdf_watcher3"]
          },
          {
            "path": "basic",
            "validators": ["$stronghold1", "$eno", "$tempo.eu.com", "$satoshipay"]
          }
        ]
```

Ended up being proper, I had misread the config info, and actually had it right at one point but was thrown off by another error. Meant to finally post that the configuration of this was not an issue, we are using different images now as well. If you end up with something along yaml issues with this, feel free to reach out but the above was what I was looking for. Thank you.

PS: shift tab that to normalize.